# Magento api for mobile app

Tags: magento-1.9, api, mobile

i've developed a mobile application for my shopping store , but i want to create a **`api`** to retrieve all store data `(category,product, payment method, cart, ...)`.

**Any suggestions or tutorial to create my own api ?**

Comment: refer http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: @PradeepSanku thank you for your comment but Which is better between `XmlConnect` and `Soap`  ?